# Calculate the sum of i^2453467 mod 2453468 for 1<=i<=999999 (^ means power)

Tags: python, algorithm, exponentiation, coding-efficiency

How to do this type of problems efficiently in less time? I have tried to do this problem in Python but it's taking so much time. I have been thinking that maybe `^` mean xor not power but according to them it was power. This is a problem from a coding competition.

Comment: Are the constants (i.e. 2453467 and 2453468) fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python code

```
answer = 0
for i in range (1, 1000000):
    answer += pow(i, 2453467, 2453468)
print answer % 2453468
```

The speed seems fast enough

Comment: You actually need to print `answer%2453468`, or better have `answer = (answer + pow(...)) % 2453468` inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

In general case, yes, you should better use modular exponentiation, and this is indeed rather simple, as @F.Ju shown. However, with a bit of math you can calculate the sum completely with pen and paper<sup>1</sup>.

The key thing to note is the fact the the exponent (`2453467`) is very close to the modulus (`2453468`), and this calls for a much simpler representation of `x^2453467 mod 2453468`. Indeed, if 2453468 were prime, then `x^2453467 mod 2453468` would be always `1` according to the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

It is not prime though, but it has a very simple representation of `2*2*613367`. So we can remember the [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), and find that `phi(2453468)` equals to `1226732`, and so `2453467=2*phi(2453468)+3`. Thus for every `x` that is relatively prime with `2453468` we have `x^1226732=1`, and, as `2453467` is `1226732*2+3`, we have `x^2453467 mod 2453468=x^3 mod 2453468`.

Let us then consider the numbers that are not relatively prime to `2453468`. In out range (1 to 999999) there are three kinds of numbers that are not relatively prime to `2453468`. One is `613367`, and it is relatively easy to proof that `613367^(2k+1) mod 2453468=613367` for each `k`.

The other kind are numbers divisible by 4. For a number `x=4k` we need to find `(4k)^2453467 mod (4*613367)`. It is equivalent to `4*(4^2453466*k^2453467 mod 613367) mod (4*613367)` and by little Fermat's theorem this reduces to `(4k)^3 mod (4*613367)`.

The final kind is the numbers divisible by 2, but not 4, and they can be treated the same was as the previous kind.

As a result, we have that

> For every `x` from 1 to 999999,
>
> ```
> x^2453467 mod 2453468 = x^3 mod 2453468
> ```

Hence, we need to calculate

```
sum(x^3) mod 2453468
```

for `x` from 1 to 999999.

But the sum under the modulus operation is, as is well known, just `(n(n+1)/2)^2`, with `n` being `999999`. Therefore, our answer is `499999500000^2 mod 2453468`, which evaluates to `2385752`.

<sup>1 Well, almost. I used Python to do simple arithmetic.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Focus on the Memory efficient method of calculation. Should be pretty straightforward to implement.

Comment: I think `Right-to-left binary method` seems better